# Is it possible to make annotations be applicable to fields of a specific type?

Tags: java, annotations

For instance, in the follwing annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EndOfTheCurrentDay {
    //some staff
}
```

it is obviously that we can't apply the annotation to the field of the type, say, `Integer`. But in the way it was implemented, the usage of the annotation may be unsafe. How can I prevet applying the annotaion to the field other than `java.util.Date`? Is it even posible?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you're using Java 8 you should really consider switching to the [`java.time`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) API because it is *much* easier to work with than the old `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot reliably restrict this and generate errors during compilation - annotation processors can be disabled. If you want to be absolutely certain you need to validate it in runtime when you process the annotation:

```
void processAnnotations(Field f) {
    EndOfTheCurrentDay annotation = f.getAnnotation(EndOfTheCurrentDay.class);
    if(annotation == null) {
        return; // Nothing to do
    }
    if(Date.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
        throw new Error("The @EndOfTheCurrentDay annotation may only be applied to fields of type Date");
    }
    // Do something with the field
}
```

Comment: What this method is tied to? Where should I implement it?

Comment: Wherever you process your annotation

Comment: @user3663882 Annotations by themselves do nothing, they attach data to a field/parameter/method/class.

Comment: @psychollek: Annotation processors aren't meant for this - they should be used for code generation, not compilation errors since they can be disabled (and are disabled by default in IntelliJ for example). I'll reword my answer a bit though

Comment: As long as you have a maven build - they are used by default - as well as in gradle. Why ? Because they are enabled by the java compiler itself.
The fact that Intelij decided not to honor this in its internal build is not a reason to say that a standard feature of java compiler cannot be reliably used.
And if you write a library you can include an annotation processor and expect that it is actually being used - if someone decides that he knows better and switches annotation processors off - it is kind of his problem.

Comment: Well, I'm going to let my answer stand as is now. I don't think this is what annotation processors should be used for. Besides if the two major IDEs have it disabled by default (IntelliJ and Eclipse) I definitely think it qualifies as not being reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can cause the compiler to issue an error message if you write the annotation on a field of the wrong type.

You cannot do this through the standard @Target meta-annotation.  Instead, you need to write an annotation processor.  The annotation processor will examine each occurrence of the annotation `@EndOfTheCurrentDay` in your source code, and it issues an error (just like any other compiler error) if `@EndOfTheCurrentDay` is applied to a non-`Date` type.  This is a short, simple annotation processor to write.

You will only get the compile-time warning when running the annotation processor, but you can add the `-processor ...` command-line argument to javac in your project's buildfile.

Answer (score 2):

write an annotation processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("org.example.EndOfTheCurrentDay")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class EndOfDayAnnotationsProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{

    @Override
    public boolean process(
            Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv)
    {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotations.iterator().next()))
        {
            if(!element.asType().toString().equals(Date.class.getName())){
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(ERROR,"annotation @EndOfTheCurrentDay can only be applied to java.util.Date!",element);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and register in META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor